# Defining variable inside of loops

Tags: javascript

Why this is not true and VSCode gives me an error:

```
req.body.scores.forEach(score => var scores += score);
```

But this is true:

```
ali = () => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var value = somearray[i];
    };
}
```

var defined inside of both!

Answer (score 1):

`var scores` is not an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions).

It is a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) and this is not allowed inside of [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) without a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

Even if you take a block statement, `scores` is not known outside of the callback.

Beside that, the variable needs an inital numerical/string value, because you want to add another value to it.

Comment: The variable second block is also in block statement. Does that mean I can not read ```value``` outside of the block statement?

Comment: Crazy JS. So variables that declare by var is not global?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `var` and `+=` operator at the same time.

Add a block statement with `{}` and init the value if it's not created.

```js
[1, 2, 3].forEach((score) => { 
   if(typeof scores === "undefined") scores = 0;
   scores += score; 
   console.log(scores);
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `return` cannot be followed my statement. In arrow function anything with `()` or without `()` is `return` value of the arrow function.
According to [Syntax Of `return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Syntax)

> **return [[expression]];**
>  
>   The expression whose value is to be returned. If omitted, undefined is returned instead

#### Note:

`var x = 0` is a statement but `x = 0` is not statement is an exprssion